# Including AngularJS modules in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've recently been trying to learn AngularJS, but I can't seem to get my HTML to see the angular module I've made. The bindings seem to work if they don't interact with the module...

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="productsModule">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
 <script src="../lib/dependencies/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../lib/dependencies/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="../scripts/products.module.js"></script>
 
 <title>ProductsTestPage</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-contoller="ProductListJSController as productList">
  <h1>Product Test Page</h1>
  
  <span>Total number of products: {{ productList.total() }}</span>
  
  <span>{{ productList.test }}</span>
 
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Price (£)</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in productList.products">
     <td>{{product.id}}</td>
     <td>{{product.name}}</td>
     <td>{{product.price}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 
  <p> 1 + 2 = {{1+2}} </p>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```js
angular.module('productsModule', [])
 .controller('ProductListJSController', function(){
  //var productList = this;
  
    this.test = 'test';
  
    this.products = [
    {id: 53, name:'gnome 1', price: 50},
    {id: 54, name:'gnome 2', price: 70},
    {id: 55, name:'gnome 3', price: 90}];
    this.total = function(){
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach(this.products, function(){
    count += 1;
    });
    return count;
    };
});
```

I'm pretty sure I've done everything right, and it's mostly the same as the examples I've found, but it just doesn't seem to display any of the bindings refering to the product module.

Comment: ok what problem you are facing ? your controller is not applied in DOM ? or what error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all. The page will display, and all the static HTML appears fine. Even the {{1+2}} expression works. But anything that refers to the actual stuff in the JS file (like {{productList.test}}) doesn't appear at all.

Comment: `{{...}}` if your expression is working fine means your controller is working with DOM. now just check in console that `productList.test` object. is there any entry in it or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your spelling:

`<div ng-contoller="ProductListJSController as productList">`

Should be:

`<div ng-controller="ProductListJSController as productList">`

Comment: Well, now i feel silly... I'd like to blame the lack of code suggestions in my IDE, but it's mostly just me being an idiot at this point... Cheers for spotting that.

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes. Just be sure to mark this as correct so people don't try and problem solve. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$scope`:-

```
angular.module('productsModule', [])
  .controller('ProductListJSController', function($scope){
    //var productList = this;

     $scope.test = 'test';

     $scope.products = [
          {id: 53, name:'gnome 1', price: 50},
          {id: 54, name:'gnome 2', price: 70},
          {id: 55, name:'gnome 3', price: 90}];
     $scope.total = function(){
          var count = 0;
          angular.forEach(this.products, function(data){
            count += 1;
          });
          return count;
     };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-contoller="ProductListJSController">

<span>{{ test }}</span>
```

Comment: I had tried that before. Just tried again and it still didn't work. Again, I've sen that work in examples, but I've also read in the documentation that it shouldn't really be done that way anyway, which is why I tried the other way.

Comment: It should work..  What value you are getting in console?  Add console on each steps.. Or even if you did not get any clue then may be you have some other issue

Comment: billyg solved my issue: spelling mistakes ruin everything.